# UML class diagram with back-references

Tags: python, oop, uml, aggregation, class-diagram

I have created an UML class diagram for my Python project, but I have no experience with that (and I'm not a professional programmer).

At first, here is the class diagram:

[image: Class Diagram]

The central or root object is the Simulation object, without it nothing else exists. Many object have a backreference to the Simulation Object, such as Atoms or Cell. xml_hanlder is the inputdata in xml-form. Many objects have a direct back-reference to to this original xml-inputdata, such as Atoms and Cell. Of course they could also access xml_handler-object via the Simulation object since they have a reference to it.

So my questions are:

1. Have I modeled the back-references correctly in the UML diagram?
2. Is it bad coding style to have such back-references since they are not really needed? It clutters the UML diagram.
3. Actually there are more objects in my diagram which also have such a back reference to xml_handler, but I have not included it to avoid too much cluttering. Is it ok to leave them out (and the diagram still being correct)?
4. The Constraints object has a backreference to the Simulation object, have I correctly modeled this as a aggregation relation?
5. Do you have any other suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual it depends on what exactly are you modelling.

If you're modelling the domain you should probably rule out the data handler completely. Also the back-reference is irrelevant and can be ignored.

If you're documenting your code, showing both data handler and back-reference is fine since those are also elements manipulated by the system.

Back-reference would be backward navigability if you had a direct relationship. Since it is indirect, you might want to show all elements contained in the xml as shared aggregation with xml-handler being a master end (with diamond). Mark it as derived on both ends (with a slash). Mark navigability from object to a containing it handler.

If you want to show just the reference without going into the actual fact of being contained use a simple association rather than shared aggregation. You should alsomark it as derived.

The same applies for back-reference between Constrain and Simulation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer.